# How a grid works when passed to the next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, grid

Assuming I have about 500 rows of data and are within a grid showing 40 rows per page. 
I been thinking about how the grid works is that the 500 rows to display the next page with the data correspond.?

I have 2 options .... 
1 The first is that you make a single queryto BD, and keep 500 rows in memory and work from there and cut each time you pass page.

2nd Second, run the query to the database, Cut to show the necessary rows and then display. And every time I pass page make a new query, bringing the 500 and go cutting data and showing only what is needed.

So the question is what is the ideal operation that should have a grid to handle the data? Making the best use in performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to take a look at more general case, which is  there are N rows in a dataset and you need to  show M on a page, it would be clear that with N big enough, in most cases, it does not make sense to load all data in memory ( however you might do this in order to warm up a cache etc )

So usually you are loading one page at a time from database, passing `pageNumber` and `pageSize` parameters to the query.

Also you might use client side caching and save old page when navigating to new one. Having LocalStorage, WebSql etc in a browser makes it really easy.

```
 function getNewPage(pageNumber, pageSize) {
      var cacheKey = pageNumber + '_' + pageSize

      if (myCache.contain(cacheKey)) { 
         return $.deferred().resolve(myCache.get(cacheKey))
      }

      return $.ajax( url , { pageSize:pageSize, pageNumber: pageNumber }, function (data) {
           myCache.set(cacheKey, data)
           return data
      } )
 } 

 var myCache = { 
    contain: function(key) {
       return !!sessionStorage.getItem(key)
    },
    get: function(key) {
       return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key)
    },
    set: function(key, o) {
       sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(o)) 
    } 
 }
```

and somewhere in some button click handler:

```
 getNewPage(0,10).done(function(data) {
     var template = _.template('<tr><td>{field1}</td><td>{field2}</td></tr>')
     $myTableTbody.html(data.map(template))
 })
```